# angularJS 1.2 code not working propely

Tags: angularjs

Here is my AngularJS 1.2 code it is not working as expected.

Can you take a look and help me out?

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('customersCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.getPeople = function (count) {
    // json callback not working
    $http.jsonp('http://www.filltext.com/?rows=' + count +
      '&fname = { firstName } & callback = JSON_CALLBACK ').success(function (data) {
      $scope.people = data;
    });
  };
  $scope.countSelection = 10;
  $scope.getPeople($scope.countSelection);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its going to $http error callback because you have given white-spaces in '& callback = JSON_CALLBACK' there has to be no spaces so code will be as :

```
$http.jsonp('http://www.filltext.com/?rows=' + count +
                '&fname={firstName}&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
```

[Here is Working Demo for your code](http://jsfiddle.net/yu24xems/)

Comment: Thank you, above code working fine , but I've another issue like:

Comment: <div class="container" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

        <select ng-model="countSelection" ng-options="n for n in [5,10,15,20]"></select>
        <div ng-repeat="person in people">

            <input type="text" ng-model="person.fname">

        </div>
    </div>

Comment: actually there is no property 'fname' in your response, its 'fname ' with a space at end, so here also you have to remove spaces http://www.filltext.com/?rows=' + count +
                '&fname={firstName}&callback=JSON_CALLBACK

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.getPeople = function (count) {
    // json callback not working
    $http.jsonp('http://www.filltext.com/?rows=' + count +
      '&fname = { firstName }', function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  };
  $scope.countSelection = 10;
  $scope.getPeople($scope.countSelection);
}]);
```